# how to escape a variable in blade templates for vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm building a Laravel application using blade templating and Vue as front-end framework.

In a template I have a table that I render as a Vuetify component:

```
@extends('layouts.authenticated')

@section('subMenu')
    @include('ingestion._sub-menu')
@endsection
@section('content')
 <div class="listFiles">
      <v-data-table
              :headers='@json($headers)'
              :items='@json($files)'
              class='elevation-1'>
          <template slot='items' slot-scope='props'>
              <td class='text-xs-left'>@{{ props.item.fileName }}</td>
              <td class='text-xs-left'>@{{ props.item.annotatedDateMilliseconds }}</td>
              <td class='text-xs-left'>@{{ props.item.metadataContact}}</td>
              <td class='justify-center layout px-0'>
                <a href="@{{props.item.id}}">
</a>
              </td>
          </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <v-btn id="start-source-import" icon>
        <v-icon>add_to_photos</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
  </div>
@endsection
```

In the `web.php` file I have specified the `headers` and the `files` objects:

```
    $headers = [
        ["text" => "Filename", "value" => "fileName", "align" => "left"],
        ["text" => "Date", "value" => "processDateTime", "align" => "left"],
        ["text" => "Owner", "value" => "metadataContact", "align" => "left"],
    ];

    $files = [
        [
            "id" => "5-4cd6-8164-5a04f2dadd5c",
            "fileName" => "filename",
            "processDateTime" => "2018-08-14 10:36:15",
            "metadataContact" => "06075-CA-San_Francisco-proper",
        ],

            "id" => "6ba6-8164-5a04f2dadd5c",
            "fileName" => "filename",
            "processDateTime" => "2018-08-14 10:36:15",
            "metadataContact" => "06075-CA-San_Francisco-proper",
        ]
    ];
    return view('ingestion/queue', [
        'files' => $files,
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
```

The problem that I'm having right now is that I can't make the `<a>` element tag to work:

```
    <a href="/ingestion/queue/@{{props.item.id}}">
```

I want a different `href` for every row of the table but with that syntax I get this error:

```
- href="/ingestion/queue/{{props.item.id}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
```

But then, if I add the v-bind:

```
    <a :href="/ingestion/queue/@{{props.item.id}}">
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags in
with(this){return _c('div',{attrs:{"id":"app"}},[_c('div',{attrs:{"id":"mainMenuWrapper"}},[_c('v-toolbar',{attrs:{"dark":true}},[_c('logo-geophy'),_v(" "),_c('a',{staticClass:"a-to-button...
```

plus lines and lines of dark code

If I extract that code somewhere inside the table it print the correct file id...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use interpolation (`{{ }}`) inside attributes for Vue 2.

You can bind an expression instead:

```
<a :href="'/ingestion/queue/' + props.item.id">
```

This just binds a string with concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. Specially when you need to use the routes by their names.

I call a function in the `href` like this

`<a :href="detailUrl(props.item.id)"></a>`

And in the methods the function looks like

```
detailUrl(id){
  return "{{route('ingestion.queue', '')}}"+"/"+id;
}
```